# Referencing logical operators

Tags: semantic-web, logical-operators, vocabulary

I want to store tuples `{a implies c, not c,...}`. How do I reference the operators? Is there a specific vocabulary I should use?

*edited after first comment*

Comment: An interesting question,but probably off topic for Stack Overflow, since it's essentially a resource request.  I don't know whether you'll find what you're looking for,since there is no standard way of representing logical formulae in RDF, so far as I know.  (That said, I'd  be interested in one;  if you end up having to develop this yourself,  feel free to  ping me, as I'd  be interested in contributing.)

Comment: Even after the edit (or maybe especially after the edit) this is still essentially a resource request: **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."**  A "specific vocabulary" here is essentially a software library.  For what it's worth, you might find [OpenMath](http://www.openmath.org/) helpful: *"OpenMath is an extensible standard for representing the semantics of mathematical objects."*  If that looks helpful, then you may want to...

Comment: follow it up with ["Mathematical Computations for Linked Data Applications with OpenMath"](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-921/openmath-01.pdf) which looks at ways to work with that representation and RDF.

Comment: Also see this other Stack Overflow question, [Encoding mathematical properties in RDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24134785/encoding-mathematical-properties-in-rdf).

Comment: Well, [logical disjunction](http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1651704)...